# ADB not responding

Tags: adb, macos, android-studio

Multiple times per day, ADB suddenly stops responding. After this occurs, every `adb` shell command fails to finish or produce any output. IntelliJ and Android Studio no longer recognize my phone(s).

The solution is straightforward: run the command

```
killall adb
```

However, I find myself needing to do this repeatedly, approximately every 15-30 minutes, which significantly hampers my development workflow. Each time I perform this action, I have to restart my Flutter application. Do you have any suggestions for resolving this issue?

I am using a New M2 MacBook Pro with Ventura 13.6, and ADB was installed via the Jetbrains SDK Manager (SDK Platform-Tools):

[image]

Comment: Also posted on Apple.SE: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465177/95704

Comment: I do have the same problem. Last weeks it just helped to run adb kill-server. But since days even this call times out and nothing happens until i kill all adb services. Do you use any "bad" security tools such as Zscaler, Cyberark, ...?

Comment: @TimoBähr It is a company PC so some security tools are installed, for example SentinelOne and Netskope.

Comment: Do you have any other Android devices connected, or Android emulators running?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used adb on macOS, but I had similar problems with it on Linux, and cured them by starting adb manually with sudo.

Kill any existing server demon with:

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

Then start it with

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Then see how things go from there.

Comment: I can not execute this command because it will never finish, just like all other adb commands.
If I use killall adb to terminate adb. Then I am able to execute those commands, but it does not prevent adb from getting stuck sometime later.